# Perfboard dimensions

Tags: pcb, breadboard

I would like to design a 3D printed enclosure for my project.

I am using [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Anpro-Board-Double-Prototype-Universal/product-reviews/B076TD6BR7/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews) perfboards from amazon. I could not find online the dimensions for the mounting holes. I know I can use a calliper, but I was wondering if there is some kind of standard for hole size, distance from edge, etc.

[image]

EDIT
Based on the comments I decided to test the measurements with a calliper. I have designed a simple model to do this that should use very little material.

[image]

Comment: You are finding out the problem with Amazon purchases. "No datasheet? No sale!" Include a photo of the part in your question rather than a link to an Amazon catalog page which will die at some stage and render your question useless to others.

Comment: Highly doubt there is any standard regarding the mounting holes. And even if there were i would still recommend using calipers to ensure it's correct.

I might add that the standard pitch for the pcb holes are 2.54 in case that was unclear.

Comment: @cutdact The pitch is specified in the description. My hope was that there was a standard for mounting holes as well. This would avoid wasting plastic with test prints.

Comment: The test prints can be as simple as four circles, just to verify the dimensions.